# jquery get value from input by id with variable and specific name

Tags: jquery, selector

I need the value from this input field:

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
<?php $pl_id=foo;?>
<input type="text" id="<?=$pl_id?>" name="projekt_leistung_anzahl" value="">
```

This not works:

```
$("#'+id'[name=projekt_leistung_anzahl]").val();
```

Comment: please explain the problem more specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution

```
var wert_projekt_leistung_nettopreis_einzel = $("input[id="+id+"][name='projekt_leistung_nettopreis_einzel']").val();
```